# How to pass phone number from recyclerview to phone dialer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, call

I'm trying to pass phone number from firebase
realtime database to recyclerview and have a Imagebotton. When you click on, it is supposed to open the phone dialer. Also, I did write the CALL_PHONE permission in Manifest.xml:

```java
    
    package com.ir;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.core.Context;
    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
    
    
    
    public class MainAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainModel,MainAdapter.myViewHolder> {
        public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options) {
            super(options);
        }
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {
          holder.name.setText(model.getName());
          holder.category.setText(model.getCategory());
          holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
          holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
          holder.about.setText(model.getAbout());
          holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
    
    
    
    
            Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
                    .load(model.getTurl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    .circleCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                    .into(holder.img);
    
            holder.Btn_Call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
```

This is where I have issue. First, I tried `startActivity(intent);`, but it didn't work. Then, I tried `context.startActivity(intent);` which didn't work either.

```java
                   String mobileNo = model.getPhone();
                   String call = "tel:" +mobileNo.trim();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                   intent.setData(Uri.parse(call));
                   Context.startActivity(intent);}
            });
        }
    
    
    
    
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item,parent,false);
    
            return new myViewHolder(view);  }
    
    
    
    
        class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            CircleImageView img;
            ImageButton Btn_Call;
            TextView name,category,email,about,phone,address;
    
    
            public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                Btn_Call = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
                img = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
                name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
                category = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categorytext);
                email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
                phone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                address = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
                about = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.about);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need permission to open the dialler. Add a breakpoint and check whether the listener gets called upon tapping the button. Meanwhile, you are using the wrong `Context`. Change the import statement of the `Context` to `import android.content.Context`.

Comment: thanks for replying Roshana . i tried that but still not working , gives me this error Non-static method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem now, you don't have an instance of the `Context`. Obtain it from a `View`. Try `holder.name.getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Just like how you have taken it into Glide, `Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())...`.